# How to make a Win Service run Long Term with Threading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, workflow-foundation-4, threadpool

I have a win service hosting a few workflows (a WorkflowApplication and a WorkflowServiceHost) that I need to keep long running. Because OnStart() requires that it completes and returns to the OS, I have a main method that fires on another thread in a threadpool. My Onstart() mainly looks like this

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
     eventLog.WriteEntry("Service starting...");
     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ServiceMainThread));
     Thread.Sleep(100);
     eventLogCms.WriteEntry("Service Started.");
}
```

ServiceMainThread() is the method where my workflows execute and core functionality is implemented. When I start the service on my Windows 7 machine it runs and then dies after approximately 8 minutes. On Win Server 2008, the thread NEVER executes.

So I think I've implemented threading incorrectly and what's `ServiceMainThread` is a bit shakey. I'm open to suggestions to what could be improved or any direction as I'm new to threading in .Net. Basic threading code in ServiceMainThread is coded as such:

```
private void ServiceMainThread(object state)
{
    // .. execute workflows ..
    eventLog.WriteEntry("Workflows executed.");

    while(alive)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        // ... check workflow states and ensure they're still executing ...
    }

    // .. halt workflow executions and perform persist operations if necessary ..
    eventLog.WriteEntry("Workflows halted.");
}
```

And for full illustrative purposes here is my OnStop() implementation:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    alive = false;
    this.haltEvent.WaitOne(); // haltEvent is of type ManualResetEvent 
}
```

Is there anything obvious that I could change to make my workflows remain in the execution state long term? The while loop seems a little too hackish (not to mention I don't like having to delay the thread for any amount of time as it is) and I'm sure there may be a better solution.

Using a Thread instead of a thread pool did ok starting but it seemed to allow the workflow run for 2minutes before execution started and stopping is now broken but I think I may be able to correct OnStop(). When I did that I set the while loop in ServiceMainThread() to an empty block so it doesn't block the thread the workflows are executing on.

**Update:**
I get this exception from .Net in event logs:

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
Stack:
   at Ptm.ServiceMainThread()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Server 2008 is 64-bit, could that have something to do with my issue?

Comment: I'm not clear why you need `ServiceMainThread`. What is this doing for you? Are the workflows themselves on other threads?

Comment: As I stated previously, if I execute my workflows from OnStart() it blocks that thread, which makes the service start timeout; making the service not runnable. So I have the main functionality of my service execute on a separate thread, allowing OnStart() to return and not trigger a timeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, for a long-running thread, create your own `Thread` object and start it; don't use the `ThreadPool`. The thread pool is designed for small, relatively short-lived operations.

Second, there are several ways that you can keep your thread alive. The most basic is what you've tried, which is a `while` loop with a sleep (or other blocking) call at the end. This is the most basic, though not necessarily the "best". There are other options, like named `WaitHandle` objects that can be accessed from other applications, that can allow for more deterministic code execution and fewer iterations of wake-check-sleep.

If, however, you either can't (or don't want to) modify the other processes to support notifying your service of particular events, then what you have is, essentially, correct. I would, however, encourage selecting a more reasonable `Sleep` time; do you *really* need to check every millisecond?

Comment: I don't need to check every millisecond, I was just trying to implement blocking. I was having the thread sleep for 2 seconds at a time and it was delaying all my workflow execution by that time span. I have reason to suspect that it may be the reason why the workflows halt execution all together after ~8 minutes.

Comment: @jlafay: Is this thread supposed to be *executing* the workflows? If so, it sounds like that should be taking place on another thread, not in the one that's supposed to monitor it.

Comment: @Adan: that's correct, it instantiates and then executes the two workflows that I wrote. They don't need to be monitored per se, I was trying different ways to perform blocking to keep while going. I've tried empty while blocks before with little success in other code.

Do you have a basic "skeleton" that you could provide as an answer to my question that includes OnStart(), OnStop(), a main execution thread method and any other necessary code? A rough idea would help out greatly and I could take it from there.

Comment: Should I possibly execute the workflows on a background worker thread asynchronously and have my dummy while loop checking to keep the service alive?

Comment: @jlafay: You're overthinking this; as long as the process has active (non-background) threads, the service will continue to run. You don't need a "keep alive" thread. If you move your processing from the `ThreadPool` to a `Thread`, you shouldn't have an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I solved that problem with my very long running Windows service by having `OnStart()` launch a `System.Timers.Timer`, and do all of the processing in the timer's `ElapsedEventHandler`.

Inside the handler I stop the timer, do the work on separate threads, check for a halt signal, and then restart the timer if it's OK to continue. The service's `OnStop()` method stops the timer and kills any active worker threads.

The worker threads handle all exceptions, so if one has a problem, it logs the exception, terminates, and then gets restarted on the next timer interval. The service core has never crashed.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your blocking, you should probably use a Wait/Pulse Programming paradigm for signalling one thread to continue. Or to just Join the thread.

[Wait & Pulse - Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Wait_and_Pulse)